# Homophone Riddle 4

Tags: riddle, word

I haven't made one in a while so here you go

```
A very small animal or a word in this question,
These animals are like what sound a clock makes
The word in this question is just in front of you
```

This might be too easy for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it a

> Mite

A very small animal or a word in this question,

> Mite is a very small animal.   Might appears in the question.

These animals are like what sound a clock makes

> Mites are like Ticks (Together they make up the subclass Acari in the class Arachnida)

The word in this question is just in front of you

> Might is in front of you in the last sentance.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess

> Duck

A very small animal or a word in this question,

> Ducklings are very tiny, and you are Duck!

These animals are like what sound a clock makes

> There may be more noises than "quack"

The word in this question is just in front of you

> You user picture is right beside the puzzle.

Comment: That should have been the answer, but no :( +1 :)